# Rails group and join with a comma

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm grouping the open hours of each day with the following loop:

```
 <% @open_hours.group_by(&:day).each do |day, open_hours| %>
      <% if day == 1 %>
        <strong>Monday:</strong>
          <% open_hours.each do |open| %>
            <%= I18n.l open.opens, :format => :custom %> - <%= I18n.l open.closes, :format => :custom %><%= "," unless open_hours == open_hours.last %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

This is what I get:

[image]

As you can see I'm trying to add a comma at the end of each array value, except for the last one:

```
<%= I18n.l open.opens, :format => :custom %> - <%= I18n.l open.closes, :format => :custom %><%= "," unless open_hours == open_hours.last %>
```

But for some reason it's not working correctly. Is there a better way to implement this????  Join the two values first with a `-` and then separate each opens-closes with a comma, except for the last value.

Comment: have you tried `unless open_hours == @open_hours.last`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Lucas Wieloch. Yes I have tried this: `<%= "," unless open_hours == open_hours.last %>` and it still shows the comma at last array value.

Comment: actually I didn't see the inner loop. I think what you want to test is this `<%= "," unless open == open_hours.last %>`. The variable `open` is the one you are using to iterate `open_hours`. It makes no sense to compare `open_hours` with `open_hours.last`

Comment: btw: Funny how you actually answered how to do this best in your own title, the answer is to use `.join(', ')` on the array instead of looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not comparing, what you think you are comparing:

```
<%= "," unless open_hours == open_hours.last %>
```

You are comparing the entire array `open_hours` to the last element of the same array `open_hours.last`

You probably wanted to compare the current opening time to check if it was the last element:

```
<%= "," unless open == open_hours.last %>
```

But anyway, there is a much nicer way to do this, if you have an array you can just join it together like this:

```
<%= open_hours.map do |open| %>
  <% I18n.l open.opens, :format => :custom %> - 
  <% I18n.l open.closes, :format => :custom %>
<% end.join(', ') %>
```

And probably it would be better to write some helper or some model method for this.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Roland Studer. This worked just fine for me: `<%= "," unless open == open_hours.last %>` unfortunately this did not: `<% end.join(', ') %>`, it show no commas.

Comment: @dev `join(', ')` will only work if you also change the `.each` to `.map` You should really learn about `.map`,  `.inject` and so forth, it will help you a lot in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about `.map` and `.inject`... I changed the `each` to `map` but the comma doesnt show

Comment: Ah, sorry, now I realize we set to output the things within the block, when we need to ouput the results of the map so the `<%=` needs to go in front of the `map` command. Generally this is something you should be doing in your model or helper and not in the view, so this problem should usually not come up.

Comment: Thanks @Roland Studer.